# Can I specify RabbitMQ credentials in node.js?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I started to use rabbit.js to connect to RabbitMQ from a node.js application.

I'm blocked at:

> Error: Channel closed by server: 403 (ACCESS-REFUSED) with message "ACCESS_REFUSED -operation not permitted on the default exchange"
>       at Channel.C.accept (/.../rabbit.js/node_modules/amqplib/lib/channel.js:398:24)
>       at Connection.mainAccept [as accept] (/.../rabbit.js/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:63:33)
>       at Socket.go (/.../rabbit.js/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:448:48)
>       at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
>   ...

which is expected, since the instance of RabbitMQ I use is configured to require the publishers and subscribers to provide credentials before being able to use the message queue, and guest account is disabled.

[The official documentation of rabbit.js](http://www.squaremobius.net/rabbit.js/) has no mention of credentials. Google searches for “rabbit.js specify credentials” and “rabbit.js login password” were inconclusive.

Are credentials supported by rabbit.js? If not, what other RabbitMQ clients for node.js support them?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

So I never used rabbit.js myself, but after diving into the code, it seems to be using [amqplib](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node). The code that parses it can be seen [here](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/blob/master/lib/connect.js#L43) and it seems it's calling the standard nodejs [URL module](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html). So perhaps you can try something [like this](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_url):

```
amqp://user:pass@host.com/vhost
```

Hope it helps!

Cheers.

Comment: Normally, fields in a connection string must be URL encoded (`%20` etc.) but it looks like the module can't handle this properly. At least a `:` in the password leads to an error even when encoded properly. Avoid special http chars like `/`, `.`, `:`, `?` in the password field!

Comment: I was just digging into the code and this was indeed a bug that [has been fixed](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/commit/7acbfd72330b835e1ffdad3daf78c222d1256142) later in 2017 :-)

Answer (score 22):

```
const amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

const opt = { credentials: require('amqplib').credentials.plain('user', 'password') };
amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', opt, (err, conn) => {});

//
```

Answer (score 12):

RabbitMQ follows the **WHATWG URL Standard**, i.e. it takes:

```
amqp://user:pass@sub.example.com:8080
```

Where:

- user: Username
- pass: Password
- sub.example.com:8080: Host:PORT

Sample code:

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

amqp.connect('amqp://example.username:example.password@localhost', (err, conn) => {});
```

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Having an '@' in the password causes issues (there may be other such characters as well), so, credentials.plain approach is better as suggested by @snakemw

```
const opt = { credentials: require('amqplib').credentials.plain('user', 'password') };
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's see how is built the connect function:

```
export function connect(url: string | Options.Connect, socketOptions?: any): Promise<Connection>;
```

As previously said you can use the url directly, eg: `amqp://user:pass@example.com:8080`.

The other option is to use `Options.Connect`:

```
const connect = {
    hostname: 'example.com',
    port: 8080,
    username: 'user',
    password: 'pass'
};
```

You can also change the `protocol` (default value 'amqp'), the `locale` (default value 'en_US'), the `frameMax` (default value 4kb), the `heartbeat` (default value 0) and the `vhost` (default value '/').

**TLDR**:

```
const hostname = 'example.com';
const port = 8080;
const username = 'user';
const password = 'pass';

// Option 1
const url = `amqp://${username}:${password}@${hostname}:${port}`;
await amqplib.connect(url);

// Option 2
const connect = {
    hostname: hostname,
    port: port,
    username: username,
    password: password
};
await amqplib.connect(connect);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to connect to RabbitMQ using object instead of a URL:

```
{
  protocol: 'amqp',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: 5672,
  username: 'guest',
  password: 'guest',
  locale: 'en_US',
  frameMax: 0,
  heartbeat: 0,
  vhost: '/',
}
```

Absent fields will be given defaults as for a URL supplied as a string ([according to the docs](https://amqp-node.github.io/amqplib/channel_api.html#connect)).